# Creating error record when SQL Server udf function returns a certain result

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, user-defined-functions

I have been wrecking my brain over this all weekend.

I have a SQL Server UDF to check whether a value passed as an argument will truncate.

```
CREATE FUNCTION willTruncate 
      (@fldValue nvarchar(200), 
       @fldSize smallint, 
       @fieldname nvarchar(40), 
       @tbl varchar(15))
RETURNS varchar(200) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    declare @Return varchar(200) 

    declare @fldLen smallint
    SET @fldLen = len(@fldValue)

    if @fldLen <= @fldSize
        SET @Return = @fldValue 
    else 
        SET @Return = left(@fldValue,@fldSize-3) + '...'

    RETURN @Return
END
```

The function works correctly to truncate the data the way I need it to when I use it in a SQL query like the sample below:

```
select top 10 
    'test' as db,
    fname,
    dbo.willTruncate(lname, 5, 'Last Name', 'People') as lastname,
    dbo.willTruncate(address,40,'Address Line 1', 'People') as addressLine1
from 
    people
```

My problem is that I need to report back in some manner about the truncations so the end users can correct the record.

I have a table to populate and have tried to insert a record as part of the else clause, a separate function and a stored procedure.  Each time I run the code it fails.

```
insert into tblTruncationErrors(trunkTable, trunkField, trunkValue) 
values(@tbl, @fieldname, @fldValue)
```

or

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.logTruncation 
    (@fldValue nvarchar(200), @fieldname nvarchar(40), @tbl varchar(15))
RETURNS varchar(30) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    declare @Return int

    insert into dbo.truncationErrors(trunkTable, trunkField, trunkValue)
    Values (@tbl, @fieldname, @fldValue)

    SET @Return = @fieldname

    RETURN @Return
END
```

or

```
CREATE PROC sp_logTruncation
    @tbl varchar(20),
    @fldName varchar(30),
    @fldValue varchar(200)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    insert into dbo.truncationErrors(trunkTable, trunkField, trunkValue)
    Values (@tbl, @fldName, @fldValue)

    SET NOCOUNT OFF
    RETURN 1
GO
```

Running it as part of the original function code fails saying it needs to be done in a function or stored procedure. If I do it as a function it says I must use a stored procedure. Using it as a stored procedure results in a message saying it can only run from a function.

So, am I writing this wrong? Is there a way to do this. I am not insistent about it going into a table so a Excel or csv file output would be wonderful as well.

Comment: Function **cannot** have side effects, e.g. alter database state, so you **cannot** insert, update or delete data in your function. [See the relevant MSDN documentation on user-defined functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191007.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Please be kind to your brain. Wrecking it is not a good idea.